# Creating an array of objects in an object - Powershell

Tags: arrays, object, powershell

I wish to create an array of events in a calendar.
Both Event and Calendar are Objects.
I couldn't find any documentation for the creation of a simple array in an Object.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this -

```
$cal = New-Object -Type PsObject -Prop @{
    Year = 2013
    Events = @()
}

$event = New-Object -Type PsObject -Prop @{
    Date = [DateTime] "2013-02-14"
    Name = "Valentines Day"
}

$cal.Events += $event
```

If you have a predefined calendar objects which doesn't have a property to store events you can use `Add-Member` to attach a new property and store an array in there.